# How to Remove the Warning "Frame for Button will be different at run time."

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I am using Xcode 5 developer preview. When I change or add a in the XIB file from interface builder Xcode shows this warning:

> Frame for Button will be different at run time.

How do I remove this warning?

Comment: WWDC 2013 session 406: "Taking Control of Auto Layout in Xcode 5"
https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/ Learn the AutoLayout.

Comment: In my case it was something with the storyboard that must have been corrupted. Cutting (CMD-X) from the storyboard the object (a collection cell) and pasting it back (CMD-V) fixed it. I waste hours redoing all the constraints before that...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Probably you have created a conflict in constraints. To resolve it
Open nib file Go to editor > Resolve all constraint issues> from there you can reset all/desired constraints.

Comment: Don't remove your constraints, fix them instead, see [Enrico's answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21199044/1693173)

Comment: As of Xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b), I've found "Resolve all constraint issues" to cause more problems and re-break things I've fixed, Bart's (http://stackoverflow.com/users/461844/bart-simpson) solution below worked for me.

Answer (score 129):

This warning is displayed when the actual position of the element is different in your storyboard than while running the app.

You can select that element and then hit <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>.

This will update the position of the element in the storyboard and that warning will go away.

You can also find this option in menu under `Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Update Frames`.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer doesn't have more up votes. Resolved it in 2 seconds for me. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. This should considered as the best answer.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that it's a shortcut for Update Frames option in Resolve Auto Layout Issues.

Comment: What causes this warning, i.e. why are the positions different?

Comment: @JarrodSmith See this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50319/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2

Comment: Sometimes the only way to make this go away is to clean the build folder and/or restart Xcode.