# Xcode Interface Builder 9.1 Collection View Cells have too small "expected height"

Tags: interface-builder, uicollectionviewcell

Recently, I encountered a problem with the Interface Builder which I failed to solve. I'm using a UICollectionViewController and whenever I add a Cell it immediately shows a orange rectangle (indicating a auto-layout update). Updating the frame/cell doesn't change anything. The warning associated with the orange marking reads "Expected: height=Y, Actual: height=X" where Y is **always** *exactly* X-100. That is: When I set a custom cell height of 193, it says "Expected: height=93". This happens no matter which size I enter.

The problem with this is that I have many difficulties with the subviews and their constraints. For instance, if I add a subview with the constraint to keep the same height as the cell, it will be shown as 93 (the expected height), even though my cell should be 193. Layouting becomes impossible.

I tried adding a new cell, same issue. I tried removing every subview and re-adding them, nothing.

Any ideas are highly welcome.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I have the same problem, and this is the only mention of it I have found online.

Comment: This bug is so annoying.

Comment: Same here. Seems to occur when I have non-standard size for the collection view controller. In my case I was embedding it inside a container view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solved it, but the warning and issue disappeared once I did the following:

Select the CollectionViewController in Interface Builder and set the size to freeform and make the height larger, large enough to show all your template cells. (Plus: maybe refresh the views). That solved the issue for me.

Comment: this worked for me, but i had to delete the segue leading to it first.

Comment: This solves this problem temporarily, but in my storyboard the issue returns after Interface Builder think about it long enough.  (For example, when re-opening the storyboard in IB, the warnings may return.)  It seems like a bug in Xcode that has been there for several versions now.

Answer (score 13):

## Solution found ! (Xcode 9.2)

The bug seems to only happen when you try to embed the `UICollectionViewController` in a `Container View` in the storyboard. **The workaround is to remove the segue while you set your constraints, and re-add the segue once your constraints are well set.**

I also think that setting `UICollectionViewController` size as `Freeform` could be responsible of the bug. If so, try to set constraints before changing the size.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I have added two collection view cell, withing collection view Controller.Only setting the view controller to free form wont help us. Need to update the size, to get rid of the warning.

updating collection view cell frames, wont help us. Warning will be continuously changing its length.

[image: Get rid of story board warning]

I tried to work without considering the warning, as I have set my collection view cell size programmatically and it does working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a strange bug
I delete the collectionViewController in SB, then create a new one, the problem disappear

Answer (score 1):

This is a common bug with Interface Builder. I don't know the exact cause, but I believe it's something to do with placing collection views inside arrangement views that do not have an exact size. I've seen it when putting them in scroll views, stack views and container views.

There is a simple fix, although I believe this to be a bug in IB that ought to be corrected by Apple rather than hacking around it. The solution (for me at least - your mileage may vary!) is to place the collection view inside an ordinary `UIView` and pin its edges to it, then place that parent view in the position that you wanted your collection view with all the constraints it required.

I usually found that there were actually no auto layout issues at run-time, which is why I believe this to be purely an Interface Builder bug.